# Car Mechanic Simulation

Tags: motorcycle, car

I have a fascination with engines- I already own a motorbike and have spent loads tinkering with it and other projects and have spent thousands on tools and stuff so I can do this. I'm only a student so I don't have the money to buy a car as well -especially with insurance being so high and also I can't afford to spend more money on tools which are car specific. 
Money for tools was already a painful hurdle to overcome for my bike and projects and I'm not prepared to do it all again just to fund my interest in car engines and cars especially when I don't actually need to drive right now.
I was looking for some cheap ways to do this- how do these two sound:

-Electude Simulator Challenge

and

-Car mechanic simulator 2018

are they realistic?

Comment: I don't know about *Electude*, as it looks like a teaching platform, but *Car Mechanic Sim* only a game. Really, the best way to *start* learning about cars is to read. Figure out a subject which interests you and start reading. Something else is, there's a lot of stuff which will transpose from bikes to cars when it comes to wrenching, with both knowledge *and* tools.

Comment: I created a login for *Electude* and went through one of the simulations. It could be useful if you already have a basis for vehicle diagnostic troubleshooting, but if you don't know which parts are what, you're going to get frustrated with it and you'll find you're just Removing/Replacing (R&R) parts to figure out what the issues are. Learning the systems and understanding how a car works through reading is going to be the best place to start, IMHO.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I gave up on the first test, the interface and limitations on what you can do are too frustrating. It looks like the PCM isn't grounding the K2 relay, but I can't figure out how to test the wiring.

Comment: @Ben - I'm sure it randomizes the problems. I got through the 2nd test (of 3) without issue, but gave up quickly on the 3rd because I didn't want to mess with it any more. It's pretty funky stuff. It took me forever to figure out how to answer the first test I had, which was a dead fuel pump. Then on the 2nd test, it took me all of 20 seconds to diagnose and fix the issue, only to tell me it took 139 seconds ... go figure. No clue how it does it's time keeping. Anyway, glad I wasn't the only one who had issues ;-)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I think it's mostly figuring out the interface. The problem seemed pretty trivial and could easily be solved IRL.